# C++ Pointer and Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am teaching myself C++.  It is my first programming language and I am struggling with the wording associated with the memory allocation of pointers.

Consider this statement:

```
int *p;
int x;
p = &x;
*p = 8;

          Value
&p        1400
p         1800
*p        8
x         8
```

&p is the memory address of p.

p is the memory address pointed to by the pointer p.

*p is the value of the memory address pointed to by the pointer p.

I understand this. However the book states:

p = &x stores the address of x in p. However, no new memory is allocated.

This is confusing.  Memory has been allocated, else p would be undefined.

Now consider this statement:

```
int *p;
p = new int;
*p = 28;
```

Here, you dont need an additional variable to make *p valid and meaningful, because memory has been allocated.

So, I guess my question is:

What is the author's meaning of his statement, "Memory is not allocated.", when considering the code block?

Comment: It probably means memory was not allocated for anything other than `p` and `x`. Or no dynamic memory allocation took place. Or both.

Comment: `p = &x;` here `p` points to the memory location of `x`, so no memory has to be allocated because an already *"allocated"* (it's on the stack) memory location is shared.

Comment: That's just semantics; in C and C++ world declaring an object on the stack is not (usually) called memory allocation. On the contrary, memory allocation typically implies dynamic memory allocation. Or rather just awkward wording in that particular book.

Comment: in the first case no DYNAMIC memory (heap) is allocated since you declare variables in the stack. In the second case calling new causes memory allocation in the heap

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @RIPUNJAYTRIPATHI - C++ Programming From Problem Analysis to Program Design Third Edition by D.S. Malik Published 2006

Comment: Well, its chapter 14 in this book. But, it's in the Dynamic Variables section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> p = &x stores the address of x in p. However, no new memory is allocated.

100% true. All of the allocation was done in the preceding two lines.

```
int *p; // allocation of p here
int x; //allocation of x here 
p = &x; // no allocation here.
```

`p = &x;` is just an assignment of the location of previously allocated memory to a previously allocated pointer. Whether storage is allocated on the stack, the heap, or whatever the current system uses instead of a stack or heap is irrelevant.

For the second example,

```
int *p; //allocation of p here
p = new int; // allocation of one nameless int AND assignment of that int to p here
*p = 28; // no allocation
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.  It's an assignment statement, thus no memory was allocated.  Hmm..That being said, wouldn't the statements: int *p; p = new int;  allocate two memory locations; one for the first statement, and then another for the second statement?

Comment: Ha, okay great.  Glad we were on the same page.

Comment: For all practical purposes yes. Technically you can allocate storage and not point to it, but off the top of my head I can't think of a good reason to do this. Important side note: One or more pointers can point to the same allocation. Sometime you want this (doubly linked list  is a good example) and sometimes not. By default copying an object that contains a pointer only copies the pointer, not the allocation. This often leads to a violation of [the Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Allocating memory but not pointing to it, will be done only for alignment or padding purposes. For example, many items are page aligned or word aligned for faster access.

Comment: @RIPUNJAYTRIPATHI I think you are making some bad/non-portable assumptions or misinterpreting what's going on with packing and padding.

Comment: I am not making any assumption. I am just giving an idea on where can we use that. In all systems, this kind of programming technique is often used. For Example, if you have a custom allocator, you would want to reserve one big chunk of memory, and manage it using the allocator. The allocator would return you page/word aligned memory. In fact, some times in order to avoid page-fault programmers use only page aligned memory. This is prevalent programming practice in all systems.

Comment: Got you. Without the memory pool, it read like you were advocating allocating and deliberately leaking small chunks of memory to get alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the single word 'allocated' is used as an abbreviation for 'allocated out of ***heap storage*** using the 'new' keyword, a library routine such as 'malloc', or some other such mechanism (directly or indirectly)'.

Here the statement 'p = &x;' means that the value of p is set to the storage address of x, which is allocated ***on the stack***.  Since the stack storage is managed automatically rather than at the programmer's discretion, we choose not to refer to this as 'allocated' in colloquial usage.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

"p = &x stores the address of x in p. However, no new memory is allocated."  Because 'x' was created on the *stack*, not on the heap (just like the variable 'p', and all other 'local variables'). It seems your 2nd example is incorrect, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Isn't stack allocation memory allocation?

Comment: Technically yes, but it's created/accounted for by the compiler at compile-time -- at a known (possibly relative, not absolute) location.

Comment: It is, but the assignment `p = &x` does not perform any *new* memory allocation. The memory was already allocated by the declaration of `p`.

Comment: ^^so when OP quoted the author, technically the author was incorrect -- memory was allocated..but statically. Generally when people say 'allocated', they mean on the heap, at run-time.

Comment: 2nd example works well (but if it's not deallocated later, leaks memory). Nit-picking: stack allocation is memory allocation iff stack is in memory :), but you might say, since pointers can take address of anything that's on stack, it's part of the C++ memory model (even if technically stack is separate, like on some microcontrollers).

Answer (score 0):

Author probably refers to heap allocation. Both p and x are allocated on stack, which is really just incrementing (or decrementing, depending on machine type) the stack pointer. They're deallocated when they go out of scope. OTOH, new int allocates it from heap memory, which probably takes more time to do, but can live longer than it's scope: you manually deallocate it using delete. Either case, pointer works well: this might be non-evident at first, but you can take the address of a variable on the stack or one that's allocated from the heap using the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is allocated on the stack when you first declare the variable. Here, memory is allocated in 
`int *p;
int x;`

So, `p = &x;` stores the memory address of x in the previously allocated memory for p on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

"p = &x stores the address of x in p. However, no new memory is allocated."

I think this probably just means that in this particular statement p takes the address of x and no new memory is allocated for x. The memory for x was probably earlier allocated but initialization of p doesn't allocate new memory for x.

But in the latter statement

```
int *p;
p = new int;
*p = 28;
```

p points to a new chunk of memory that has been allocated because it is initialized with "new int".

Answer (score 0):

Well I got that book and the explanation provided by others is correct. Just adding mine too.

When you compile a function, unless it is a variable argument one, the frame size and format is already known to compiler. Now when you call this function, compiler reserves the memory for this frame on the stack above (or below) the caller function. You can see this happening yourself.

```
void fun(){
int a,b;
printf("addr fun &a=%u, &b=%u",&a,&b);
callfun();
}

void callfun(){ int c;
printf("addr callfun &c=%u",&c);
}
```

On most architectures, address may seem decreasing - but logically by calling *calllfun()*, we created a frame **above** previous frame.

So, one can say that memory for these variables was created transparently and programmer never cared for that. When the stack grows, more memory is used, and freed when the function calls come closer to the main entry point function. But in other case, when you use new operator, programmer explicitly asks for memory in addition to what has been already allocated on the stack. This is fulfilled from another region in program's address space called **heap**. OS provides facility for doing this.

In your case, author just said that since the function carrying all these variables was already called, memory has already been allocated (on stack) in the process and NO NEW memory was created. However, you may use *new* operator to allocate more memory if you want.